# Is there an algebraic function near every smooth function?

Tags: functions, polynomials

For every real number, you can create rational numbers that are arbitrarily close to it. As a result, rational numbers are a sufficient field for every real-world problem involving real numbers, and as a result of that computers are useful for scientific purposes.

Is something similar true of algebraic functions? When I conduct an experiment I can constrain the values of a function to an arbitrary but finite precision. Will I ever be able to rule out the theory that the function I am measuring is algebraic, or are there algebraic functions arbitrarily close to every other function? (I'm excluding, of course, pathological functions like the ones that are continuous nowhere.)

Comment: yes, see Stone-Weierstrass theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: It's true if you restrict yourself to a compact domain (you can use the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem). However, it is not true for noncompact donains.

Comment: This is an excellent question. The problem is that "close" needs to be defined.  "Close" usually involves the uses of arbitrarily small open sets.  How does one define open sets in the space of all functions; what's the "distance" between two functions. To make sense of these ideas, you need to choose a topology. The ones that I am familiar with are the so-called Whitney Topologies, which involve functions differentiable with different orders. Once we decide what "close" means, then we can answer your question. I'm not being facetious  - I promise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "close" means uniformly close on the whole real line, then no.  For example, any algebraic function $f$ with $|f(x) - \sin(x)| < 1$ for all real $x$ would have infinitely many real zeros (by the Intermediate Value Theorem), but there are no such algebraic functions except $0$.